# Example of updating fields without views.py?

Tags: django, django-forms

Can you please provide an example of views.py for updating(or creating) fields without using forms.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.
Please, next time, do some research.

###### Just searching "django update or create" will give you a very nice django doc to the queryset method.

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'first_name': 'Bob'},
)
```